# PHPで一次元配列と二次元配列を比較して条件分岐したい

Tags: php

**二次元配列$aと一次元配列$bを比較して、下記3つの条件分岐を行いたいです**

- 条件1: $bの値が、$aの(特定キーの)値と一致する場合
- 条件2: $bの値の一部が、$aの(特定キーの)値に含まれない場合
- 条件3: $bの値の一部が$aの(特定キーの)値に含まれない、かつ $aの(特定キーの)値の一部が$bに含まれない場合

※何れも配列内の順番は問わない
※返り値は、配列でも可

---

**条件1: $bの値が、$aの('z_id'キーの)値と一致する場合**
TRUEを返す

```
$a = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => '2',
    'x_id' => '1',
    'z_id' => '3',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => '1',
    'x_id' => '1',
    'z_id' => '2',
  ),
)
$b = array (
  0 => '3',
  1 => '2',
)
```

---

**条件2: $bの値の一部が、$aの('z_id'キーの)値に含まれない場合**
$aの('z_id'キーの)値に含まれない$bの値を返す。下記例では2(後でINSERTで利用)

```
$a = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => '2',
    'x_id' => '1',
    'z_id' => '3',
  )
)
$b = array (
  0 => '3',
  1 => '2',
)
```

---

**条件3: $bの値の一部が、$aの('z_id'キーの)値に含まれない、かつ $aの('z_id'キーの)値の一部が、$bに含まれない場合**
aの('z_id'キーの)値が$bに含まれない該当二次元配列目の'id'の値を返す。下記例では2(後でDELETEで利用)
$aの('z_id'キーの)値に含まれない$bの値を返す。下記例では2と3(後でINSERTで利用)

```
$a = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => '2',
    'x_id' => '1',
    'z_id' => '4',
  )
)
$b = array (
  0 => '3',
  1 => '2',
)
```

---

**その他**
・「条件2」は「条件3」に含まれますか？
・「条件1」と「条件3」で場合分けして、「条件3」をさらに条件分けすれば良い？

Comment: ご質問の内容ですがマスターとなる配列`a`の要素`z_id`と、配列`b`の中の値を比較して削除するものと挿入するものを抽出するということでよいでしょうか? (そうである場合、条件2の一部は条件3に含まれていると思います)
このような処理を関数で作成する場合は、削除するIDの配列と、挿入すべき`z_id`の配列の一覧を作成して戻す、内容が完全に一致している場合はTRUEを戻す、という関数を準備するとよいと思います。そのような例を提示すればよいでしょうか?

Comment: はい。そのような例の提示をお願いします。やりたいことはコメントいただいた通りです

Answer (score 2, accepted):

コメントで詳細をいただきましたので関数を作成してみました。
質問にあった配列の書き方が5系でしたので5.6.29での確認になります。
ループで回す方法もありますが、PHPではarray系の関数がありますので利用しています。特定のカラムの抽出には、array_column、配列の比較にはarray_intersectやarray_diffを用います。

```
<?php

function testmaster($a,$b)
{
    $master = array_column($a,"z_id","id");//extract array(id=>z_id) from master

    $del = array_diff($master,$b);
    $ins = array_diff($b,$master);

    if(!empty($del)) $del = array_keys($del);//pick id of master
    if(!empty($ins)) $ins = array_values($ins);

    if(empty($del)&&empty($ins)) return TRUE;
    //
    return array($ins,$del);
}
```

テストコード込のサンプル

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/37b99cbbfb17c8247f96846a250c9f31067971e1

Comment: 期待通り動作しました。一致していない場合、返り値配列の[0]に追加分が、返り値配列の[1]に減少分が入る仕様ですね。また、array_diffは今回のケースでは使えないと思い込んでいたのですが、array_column(初めて知りました)した後、使用すれば良かったのですね